# Does TeamCity clean-up really require you to shut down the server?

Tags: teamcity

TeamCity seems to completely shut down during the clean-up process, including stopping all active builds. The only option for scheduling seems to be nightly. I have builds that take up to several days to run. Do I have any options other than disabling the scheduled process?

[image]

Even for my play server the build process took almost 30min to execute. I'm a bit worried as well about what a production server would look like, especially running daily!

Comment: "I have builds that take up to several days to run" *wow*.

Answer (score 0):

You need a heavy infrastructure in place for CI if you are planning to make it robust. See whether the build artifacts are cleared and configured properly in teamcity. Instead of doing a cleanup in one setting, you can automate it and probably remove relatively older build history periodically

And the ansewr to your question is No, cleanup does not require you to shutdown the server unless it crashes.

**Edit :** The teamcity shutdown may be due to innumerous reasons i can only speculate on. It might have gotten shut down because of a crash. But according to the policy given in Jebrains wiki, there is no mention about the server shutdown. And it is totally not logical to shutdown the entire server for a cleanup. [Source.](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Clean-Up)

Comment: I am a bit confused. Did TeamCity only shut down because I explicitly asked it to run the clean up process? If I let it run at the scheduled time, then will it do it without shutting down? Or are you saying that I need to write my own clean up routine?

Comment: I start up the server, go to Administration->Build History Clean-up Policy and then click "Start clean-up now". A popup appears with the text: "This operation may require significant time, and the server will be unavailable for all users. Are you sure you want to start clean-up process now?". I agree that the manual doesn't mention it needs to shut down but it doesn't sound like a crash either. Perhaps it is conditional but on what? I've tried running it repeatedly and the popup always appears. I am using 6.5.5.

Comment: @balor123 : I updated your question with a screenshot with the exact popup you are talking about. So, the answer to your question is that Teamcity will go into a mode of hibernation detaching itself from all users. But this is not equivalent to a shutdown. I would say a shutdown to be a total exit of the teamcity process and all its build agents.

Comment: Yes that's the one. Is there any way around hibernation mode then?